# In Gson, how can you limit booleans to true and false (not TrUe and fAlSe)?

Tags: java, gson

I don't know if this is intended behavior or not in Gson using the default `TypeAdapter.BOOLEAN`, but not only do `true` and `false` (and the Strings `"true"` and `"false"`) get deserialized as valid boolean values, but so do `TRUE` and `FALSE` (and their String versions), `True` and `False` (and their String versions), and `TrUe` and `fAlSe` (and their String versions), along with any mangling of case you'd like to try. In addition, since the `TypeAdapter` relies on Java's `Boolean.parseBoolean()`, any non-null String that isn't some case-mangling of `"true"` becomes `false`.

I'm writing a `TypeAdapter` and I would like to only allow `true` and `false` to be acceptable boolean values, but I can't figure out how to tell if the value I'm about to read is `true` or `True` or `TRUE` or `tRuE`, since I can only call `nextBoolean()` and it will return the same value for all of those.

Is there any way to get the raw value so that I can check whether it's the valid lower-case form or am I out of luck?

Comment: Why are you calling `nextBoolean()` if next object is a String? Can't you get the String and make the logic?

Comment: The default `TypeAdapter.BOOLEAN` accepts either a bare, unquoted value or a String (apparently for backward compatibility). If I don't quote the value and put `true` or `TRUE` or `True` or `tRuE`, `JsonReader.peek()` returns `JsonToken.BOOLEAN` and I can only call `nextBoolean()` to get the value. Trying to call `nextString()` throws an exception. In other words, I can't figure out a way to not accept weirdly cased booleans.

Comment: Sure, I can write my own `TypeAdapter` for Booleans. I have to implement `public Boolean read(JsonReader in)`. My problem is that `JsonReader` provides no public way to tell the difference between the tokens `true` and `TRUE` and since that's the only thing I have access to when I write a `TypeAdapter`, I can't tell the difference between them.

Comment: As to why I'd reject `TRUE`, it's because that's what the spec says. https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt Section 3. "The literal names MUST be lowercase. No other literal names are allowed." What I'm actually planning to do is accept it, but notify the sender that they're sending an incorrect value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A small summary of the comments section.

The JsonReader use a integer value to get the adapter to use to get the value corresponding. In the case of an unquoted value, the methods `private int peekKeyword()` will check the first character like this :

```
if(c == 't' || c == 'T') -> BOOLEAN
if(c == 'f' || c == 'F') -> BOOLEAN
if(c == 'n' || c == 'N') -> NULL
```

So it does accept the uppercase even if the IETF7159 states in point 3

> A JSON value MUST be an object, array, number, or string, or one of
>      the following three literal names:
>
> false null true
>
> The literal names MUST be lowercase.  No other literal names are
>      allowed.

Once the value is seen as a Boolean, it will be converted using Boolean.parseBoolean(String s), which ignore the case of the String (as expected here)

I notice that OP have open [an issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/988) on GitHub. Let's see the answers.

This API is kind of bullet proof to update so this will not be easy (or even possible) to do some changes on the accepted answers

Comment: Accepting this answer because it basically says "NO", which I think is the right answer.